# How to play PCM audio in flutter webrtc?

Tags: flutter, dart, webrtc, flutter-webrtc

I am using flutter_webrtc for streaming video from a camera. We are facing an issue like, the audio from the camera is of PCM format. Is there any way i can play PCM in flutter webrtc...